# Is it legal to sell or monetize games created with the Unity 3D free edition?

Tags: unity, legal, google-play, business-model

Is it okay to use Unity 3D programming and gaming software to create mobile game apps for Android and iOS? I am using a free version of Unity 3D and planning it to sell my current game app I've created by publishing it to Google Play. I also use this method for earning money by setting as a free app with ads on it.

I saw some developers relied on using free version of Unity 3D to create games and published it via App Store or Google Play. If it does, should I have to pay or share contribution to the Unity development team for earnings since I use the free version in order to rely for producing several game apps for business?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

From the [Unity FAQ](http://unity3d.com/unity/faq):

> ### Can we sell games and make money with the free version of Unity?
>
> Yes you can create and sell a game with the free version of Unity,
>   without paying royalties or any revenue share. However, the free
>   version of Unity may not be licensed by a commercial entity with
>   annual gross revenues (based on fiscal year) in excess of US$100,000,
>   or by an educational, non-profit or government entity with an annual
>   budget of over US$100,000.
>
> Please also be aware that the feature set of the free version is not
>   intended for the production of professional games and interactive
>   content. Lastly, games made with our Pro trial licenses may not be
>   distributed nor used for commercial purposes.

Comment: "Lastly, games made with our Pro trial licenses may not be distributed nor used for commercial purposes." So that means even either in free version or pro version, either selling my Unity 3D made game apps for free or not, there is still probability to seek for permission before publishing it depending on its case?

Comment: No, that last part is just saying you can't use a trial of the pro version (which is not the same as the free version) to produce games to sell. You don't need to seek permission to produce and sell games with the free version. You are not allowed to sell games made with the Unity Pro trial. You can produce and sell games with the non-trial Pro version.

Comment: I see. What about full Pro version, not trial, of Unity? Is it still legally safe to sell these games made of this software?

Comment: The full Pro version is the same as the non-trial Pro version I mention in the last sentence of my previous comment. Slow down man :) Read.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the help. Tips noted. I'll take it easy myself. Ha ha ha ha... :-D

Comment: @Byte56 How about the assets/libraries purchased from the Unity store? Is it still legally safe to publish or sell indie games with some of these assets attached to it from Unity store?

Comment: @DavidDimalanta What am I? Google? http://unity3d.com/legal/as_terms. See Appendix 1.

Comment: I guess if you start off doing a game in your spare time using the free version of Unity but you make more than $100,000 from it you won't be able to use it in the following year.  Perhaps you'll have to give up your license after 12 months.  Or perhaps it lasts forever because it was originally licensed to a company making less than $100,000.

Comment: @Poldie I think if you make 100k from your game, it won't be a problem to buy a Pro license.

Comment: @Byte56, haha, unless you're utterly greedy, lol.

Comment: @joltmode Only if you're irrationally greedy, paying $1500 to continue making $100k, is logically greedy. ;)

Comment: I wasn't able to find this info in the faq linked, but found the same thing here: https://support.unity3d.com/hc/en-us/articles/205253119-Can-I-make-a-commercial-game-with-Unity-Free-Personal-Edition-